# How do I derive the critical temperature for bose condensation in two dimensions?

Tags: thermodynamics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, mathematics, bose-einstein-condensate

In class we derived the 3D case, but there's a step I don't understand:

$$ N = g \cdot {V \over (2 \pi \hbar)^3} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over{e^{\left( E_p \over{K_B T}\right)}-1}} d^3 p =  g \cdot {V \over (2 \pi \hbar)^3} \cdot 4 \pi \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{p^2 \over{e^{\left( E_p \over{K_B T}\right)}-1}} dp $$

... I feel like if I knew why that step made sense, I could figure out how to do the equivalent thing for the 2D case, but I'm stuck on that.

Comment: you are just going from cartesian to spherical coordinates, $(p_x,p_y,p_z)\rightarrow(p,\theta,\phi)$, which has a jacobian of $p^2 \mbox{cos}\theta dp d\theta d\phi$. The integrand only depends on the radial coordinate, so the solid angle part integrates to $4\pi$.

Comment: @wsc I'd post that as an answer as it probably answers the question satisfactorily :)

Comment: Thanks @wsc, I thought it had something to do with that.  Since I'm having trouble, I'm going to walk through it 'out loud' here...  If $E_p$ is only a function of $p_{\rho}$, it stays unchanged, and the $p^2$ in the numerator could be called $p_{\rho}^2$.  The limits for $\rho$ remain $0$ and $\infty$, but the limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$ are reduced to their meaningful range.  Using the notation more familiar to me, $\theta$ and $\phi$ factor out to $\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\cdot\int_0^{\pi}\mathrm{sin}(\phi)d\phi=2\pi\cdot2$

Comment: ... applying that to the 2D case, converting to polar coordinates, the Jacobian is $r$, $\theta$ factors out into $\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=2\pi$, the $r$ really means $p_r$, which is just $p$, and the whole thing goes like this: $$ N = g \cdot {A \over (2 \pi \hbar)^2} \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over{e^{\left( E_p \over{K_B T}\right)}-1}} d^2 p =  g \cdot {A \over (2 \pi \hbar)^2} \cdot 2 \pi \cdot \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}{p \over{e^{\left( E_p \over{K_B T}\right)}-1}} dp $$  That makes sense to me, now I can go trip over the next step...  Thanks again @wsc!

Comment: @Polyergic, that's exactly right. @Lagerbaer, I try to avoid submitting 2-sentence responses as answers, but I suppose there isn't much more to say here. :)

Comment: Although you should expect something very bad to happen when you actually take the integral! This is typically taken as the proof that there is no BEC (for the free gas, other caveats, etc., etc.,) in 2D.

Comment: @wsc, In this case, "a quantum Bose gas of spin ultrarelativistic particles," $E_p=p c$, using Wolfram Alpha for the integration, it goes like this: $$\int_0^{\infty}{{p}\over{e^{\left({p c}\over{K_B T}\right)}-1}}dp = 6\cdot\left({\pi K_B T}\over{c}\right)^2$$ $$N = \cdots = {3 \pi g A}\cdot\left({K_B T}\over{c \hbar}\right)^2$$ $$T = {{c \hbar}\over{K_B}}\sqrt{{N}\over{3 \pi g A}}$$ ... the only thing I'm not sure about is if there's something more I'm supposed to do for spin, I'm pretty sure there wasn't anything about that in class.  Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: Ah, and there's one of the caveats :) the relativistic bose gas works just fine. Now, in the absence of anything that breaks the spin degeneracy, the only place it comes into play is as a multiplier for your density of states -- this is actually typically denoted by $g=(2S+1)$, so unless that meant something else I think you already have it.

Comment: Dang, that 6 should be 1/6... $$\int_0^{\infty}{{p}\over{e^{\left({p c}\over{K_B T}\right)}-1}}dp = {1\over6}\cdot\left({\pi K_B T}\over{c}\right)^2$$ $$N = \cdots = {{\pi g A}\over4}\cdot\left({K_B T}\over{c \hbar}\right)^2$$ $$T = {{c \hbar}\over{K_B}}\sqrt{{4 N}\over{\pi g A}}$$ Also, I noticed Alpha shows that for $E_p = {{p^2}\over{m}}$ the integral does not converge, which would mean no BEC.

Comment: @wsc, right, I was wondering that earlier and forgot, I don't see anything in the problem that indicates a value for $s$, so I guess the best I can do is substitute that in and make some comment.